# Receiving iMessages

Tags: messages

I have iMessage turned off on my phone to save data. I have recently realised I am not receiving messages off friends who have iMessage switched on on their phone. Is there anything I can do apart from turning my iMessage back on to receive these.

Answer (score 1):

You may choose to deregister from iMessage. Take a look at this  [link](https://selfsolve.apple.com/deregister-imessage). However it is only recommended when you are switching to another platform.